# Choosing and executing functions in a list of functions

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that do some random moves, and it have a lot of functions, the program select like a keyword to use the function, but my code get big for something simple, there is a simpler way to write this code?

```
list_mov = ["R", "RI", "L", "LI", "U", "UI", "D", "DI", "F", "FI", "B", "BI"]

mov = random.choice(list_mov)

# Here i need to make a list of selected functions
resolution.append(mov)

if mov == "R":
    mov_r()
if mov == "RI":
    mov_ri()
if mov == "L":
    mov_l()
if mov == "LI":
    mov_li()
if mov == "U":
    mov_u()
if mov == "UI":
    mov_ui()
if mov == "D":
    mov_d()
if mov == "DI":
    mov_di()
if mov == "F":
    mov_f()
if mov == "FI":
    mov_fi()
if mov == "B":
    mov_b()
if mov == "BI":
    mov_bi()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is an object in python. Functions included. So I can write this:

```py
list_mov = {
  "R": mov_r,
  "RI": mov_ri,
  "L": mov_i,
  ...  # fill in more here
}

mov = random.choice(list(list_mov.keys()))

# Here i need to make a list of selected functions
resolution.append(mov)
# get function, then execute it
func = list_mov[mov]
func()
```

Comment: Why not just use a list of functions?

Comment: @Tupteq Then `mov` will be functions, not the string name of the move. And `resolution` will not be a list of strings.

Comment: it doesn't work, appears this error:

File "#Some Archives#\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 291, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

i don't know what that mean, i'm a beginner at python and i don't know how the program behind it works, can you explain?@adrtam

Comment: @KronusDelta updated code. You need to make list_mov.keys() a list. Blame the difference between Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a list of functions and choose from them to a variable (as you do with strings). They all have the same parameters, so it should be easy:

```py
list_mov = [mov_r, mov_ri, ...]
mov = random.choice(list_mov)
resolution.append(mov)
# And finally
mov()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, everything is an object. You can simply do this: `list_mov = [mov_r, mov_l, ...]` 
Because of this, you can use:

```
mov = random.choice(list_mov)
mov()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually select from list of function instances, and then call the one you randomly selected, like:

```py
import numpy as np

def x():
    print("function x!")

def y():
    print("y here.")

def z():
    print("zzz")

av_functions=[x,y,z]
mv=np.random.choice(av_functions)

mv()
```